# SwiftUI - Cannot Convert ObservedObject<UserData>.Wrapper to Binding<UserData> in RegistrationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing a SwiftUI-based registration flow in my app, where a user progresses through several steps to complete their registration. The issue I've encountered involves passing an instance of UserData, which is an ObservableObject, to various child views as a Binding. Specifically, I'm stuck with the error message: "Cannot convert value of type 'ObservedObject.Wrapper' to expected argument type 'Binding'" in my RegistrationView.

I have a RegistrationView that controls the registration process and several child views for each step of the registration (like EmailRegistrationStepView, PhoneNumberStepView, etc.). These child views need to update the shared UserData object.

Despite following the standard SwiftUI approach of using @ObservedObject and passing the data as a Binding using the $ syntax, I keep getting a type conversion error. This error occurs when I try to pass userData from the RegistrationView to its child views.

Attempted Solutions & Difficulties:

I've double-checked that userData is correctly declared as an @ObservedObject and that I'm using the $ prefix for creating a Binding.
I've cleaned the build folder and restarted Xcode.
I'm using Xcode Version 15.0.1.
I attempted to simplify the code to isolate the issue, but the error persists.

Code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RegistrationView: View {
    enum RegistrationStep {
        case emailAndPassword
        case phoneNumber
        case verificationCode
        ...
    }

    @State private var registrationStep: RegistrationStep = .emailAndPassword
    @ObservedObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch registrationStep {
            case .emailAndPassword:
                EmailRegistrationStepView(nextStep: $registrationStep, userData: $userData)
            case .phoneNumber:
                PhoneNumberStepView(nextStep: $registrationStep, userData: $userData)
            case .verificationCode:
    ...
```

And then the user data is established in another file as a data model:

```swift
class UserData: ObservableObject {
    // Use @Published to automatically update views when these properties change.
    @Published var email: String = ""
    ...
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Show the relevant code,  but an observable object can't be passed to a binding. You would either just use observable object in each sub view or put the object in the environment

Comment: Since you are using `ObservableObject`, 
have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app) . Essentially you cannot pass your `class UserData: ObservableObject` as a binding. 
You can however, pass its `@Published var` properties using the `$` as a binding to another view, as described in the link, eg `$userData.name`. And as mentioned before show your code that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Just added the code! Let me know if more info is needed. I have it as a @Published var but I'll have to read about the $ as a binding. Not sure if I have it implemented correctly. Thank you very very much for your help!

Comment: try this approach: call `EmailRegistrationStepView(nextStep: $registrationStep, email: $userData.email)`
 and declare `@Binding var email: String` in your `EmailRegistrationStepView`. So that whenever you change the `email` in your `EmailRegistrationStepView`, it will be reflected in your `userData` model. Same approach for your `PhoneNumberStepView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass the whole `userData` model to your `EmailRegistrationStepView` and `PhoneNumberStepView`,
then try this simple approach, using `.environmentObject(userData)` as shown in the example code:

```
class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var phoneNumber: String = ""
    // ...
}

// outside RegistrationView
enum RegistrationStep {
    case emailAndPassword
    case phoneNumber
    // ...
}

struct RegistrationView: View {
    @State private var registrationStep: RegistrationStep = .emailAndPassword
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(userData.email).foregroundStyle(.red) // <-- to show it works
            
            switch registrationStep {
            case .emailAndPassword:
                EmailRegistrationStepView(nextStep: $registrationStep) // <-- here
            case .phoneNumber:
                PhoneNumberStepView(nextStep: $registrationStep)
            // ....
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EmailRegistrationStepView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData  // <-- here
    @Binding var nextStep: RegistrationStep  // <-- here, only if you need to change nextStep
  
    var body: some View {
        Text("in EmailRegistrationStepView")
        TextField("email", text: $userData.email).border(.green)  // <-- here, change the email
    }
}

struct PhoneNumberStepView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @Binding var nextStep: RegistrationStep

    var body: some View {
        Text("PhoneNumberStepView")
        TextField("phoneNumber", text: $userData.phoneNumber)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var userData = UserData()
    
    var body: some View {
        RegistrationView()
           .environmentObject(userData)  // <-- here
    }
}
```

Note, if you put `enum RegistrationStep` inside the `RegistrationView`,
then you need to use `@Binding var nextStep: RegistrationView.RegistrationStep` etc...
whenever you refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an update on my issue regarding the "Missing argument for parameter 'userData' in call" and "Cannot convert value of type 'ObservedObject.Wrapper' to expected argument type 'Binding'" errors I was encountering in my SwiftUI app.

Thanks to the community's input, especially from workingdog support Ukraine, I explored the approach of not passing the entire ObservableObject (UserData) as a binding to my views. Instead, I passed its @Published properties as bindings. This insight was crucial in pointing me in the right direction.

Here's a brief overview of the final solution:

RegistrationView: I modified RegistrationView to pass only the specific @Published properties from UserData as bindings to the child step views. For instance, in the case of EmailRegistrationStepView, I passed email and password as bindings.

Step Views: Each step view, such as EmailRegistrationStepView, PhoneNumberStepView, etc., was updated to accept only the necessary properties as @Binding parameters instead of expecting the entire UserData object.

Local State in Step Views: For views like VerificationCodeStepView, where we initially thought of passing a verificationCode binding, I instead used a local @State variable to manage the verification code.

This approach eliminated the type conversion errors and aligned well with SwiftUI's data flow principles. The app now correctly observes changes to UserData properties and updates the UI accordingly.

To the Stack Overflow community, thank you for your guidance. The suggestion to pass individual @Published properties as bindings was particularly helpful. If there's any further advice or best practices I should consider, I'm all ears.

@fromgisselle